# How to stop log4j from logging

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j

N.B. While I have not managed to work out the final solution to the issue, with some help from Andreas I was able to realise that I had configured log4j incorrectly and it was using a default properties file and not the one that I specified myself. I will post the solution when I have it working properly so that it is available for people in the future... right after octoberfest this weekend :D

Okay, so I know that similar questions have been asked on here, however I have yet to find a post that has this same problem or a solution to fix it.

Okay, so I tried to start using log4j to try and get used to proper logging with my code (yay best practices!) but I ran into a bit of an issue while trying to fix an error in my code. The problem is that I need to read the console output, but log4j is putting everything there (DEBUG). At first this wasn't a problem so I didn't bother to get log4j to stop doing it. But now I am finding it quite hard to look for the information that I need in the output.

As a quick solution to my problem, I tried to programmatically change the logging level to OFF on both my loggers, nope.

Then I tried to change the properties file to prevent it writing to the console, nope.

Then I tried to remove everything in the properties file thinking that log4j would no longer know how to behave, nope.

Then I tried to completely remove log4j from my code by commenting out all of the lines and not initialising any loggers, nope... wait, what?

Yep, it seems that even without any log4j code in my project, log4j just does not want to stop.

At this point I tried to clean the project (I'm using eclipse), then I tried to restart eclipse, and then my laptop.

I know that I am probably making a massive oversight, but I feel like commenting out ALL OF THE CODE  would do something.

I should note that NOTHING I tried made any difference to the content being printed, it always printed the same lines in the same order (hence why I am sure that I am doing something wrong)

Any help that can be offered would be greatly appreciated

EDIT 1: I should also state that the reason that I think it is log4j causing the issue is that all of the output in the console is taking the format that I defined in the log4j.properties file.

EDIT 2:

one class

```
public class MessageSender extends AbstractCommand{
//private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldCommandFactory.class);

private String messageText = "placeholder";
private final long MESSAGE_ID = XXXXXXXXXX;

@Override
public void execute() {
    try {
        //LOG.setLevel(Level.OFF);
        //LOG.info("MESSAGE_TEXT: "+messageText);                                                                   
        TelegramRequest telegramRequest = TelegramRequestFactory.createSendMessageRequest(MESSAGE_ID, messageText, true, null, null);
        //LOG.info("REQUEST: "+telegramRequest.equals(getRequestHandler()));
        requestHandler.sendRequest(telegramRequest);
    } catch (JsonParsingException | TelegramServerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public MessageSender(Message message, RequestHandler requestHandler){
    super(message, requestHandler);
}

public MessageSender(Message message, RequestHandler requestHandler, String text){
    super(message, requestHandler);
    this.messageText = text;
}
```

the other class

```
public class MyCommandFactory implements CommandFactory {

    //private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyCommandFactory.class);

    @Override
    public Command createCommand(Message message, RequestHandler requestHandler) {
        //LOG.setLevel(Level.OFF);
        //LOG.info("MESSAGE_ID: "+message.getChat().getId()+"  MESSAGE_BODY: "+message.getText());
        return new MessageSender(message, requestHandler);
    }
}
```

sample of output (I have removed certain sensitive information)

```
15-09-25 06:32:42 INFO  AbstractCommandDispatcher:69 - *************************************
2015-09-25 06:32:42 INFO  AbstractCommandDispatcher:70 - ** Starting up command dispatcher...
2015-09-25 06:32:42 INFO  AbstractCommandDispatcher:71 - *************************************
2015-09-25 06:32:43 INFO  AbstractCommandWatcher:50 - >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
2015-09-25 06:32:43 INFO  AbstractCommandWatcher:51 - >> Starting up command watcher...
2015-09-25 06:32:43 INFO  AbstractCommandWatcher:52 - >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
2015-09-25 06:32:45 DEBUG DefaultCommandWatcher:104 -   Polling Telegram updates (offset:0, limit:100, timeout=0)...
2015-09-25 06:32:45 DEBUG RequestAddCookies:122 - CookieSpec selected: default
2015-09-25 06:32:45 DEBUG RequestAuthCache:76 - Auth cache not set in the context
2015-09-25 06:32:45 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:249 - Connection request: [route: {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2; total allocated: 0 of 20]
2015-09-25 06:32:45 DEBUG PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:282 - Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2; total allocated: 1 of 20]
2015-09-25 06:32:45 DEBUG MainClientExec:234 - Opening connection {s}->https://api.telegram.org:443
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:131 - Connecting to api.telegram.org/
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG SSLConnectionSocketFactory:335 - Connecting socket to api.telegram.org/ with timeout 0
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG SSLConnectionSocketFactory:388 - Enabled protocols: [TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2]
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG SSLConnectionSocketFactory:389 - Enabled cipher suites:[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG SSLConnectionSocketFactory:393 - Starting handshake
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG SSLConnectionSocketFactory:423 - Secure session established
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG SSLConnectionSocketFactory:424 -  negotiated protocol: TLSv1.2
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG SSLConnectionSocketFactory:425 -  negotiated cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG SSLConnectionSocketFactory:433 -  peer principal: CN=api.telegram.org, OU=Domain Control Validated
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG SSLConnectionSocketFactory:442 -  peer alternative names: [api.telegram.org, www.api.telegram.org]
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG SSLConnectionSocketFactory:446 -  
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator:138 - Connection established 
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG MainClientExec:255 - Executing request POST 
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG MainClientExec:260 - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG MainClientExec:266 - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG headers:124 - http-outgoing-0 >> 
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Length: 28
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
2015-09-25 06:32:46 DEBUG headers:127 - http-outgoing-0 >> Host: api.telegram.org
```

EDIT 3:

log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CONSOLE

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern= %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %-5p %x %C{1} : %m%n
```

Comment: Post your code and the console output.

Comment: If changing your code does not change anything, then you are not running *that* code.

Comment: @Andreas That is what I thought too, however before I added log4j to the project it wasn't typing anything to the console except for a few specific System.out.println() statements that I wrote myself. The behaviour that is causing the problem only started after log4j was installed. So hence my confusion when I removed all log4j code and the behaviour continues :/

Comment: Are you sure your `XML` is being picked by the logger?

Comment: I'm not sure not sure what you mean exactly

Comment: That `log4j.properties` file is not the file used to configure Log4J, because it will not generate `DEBUG` output. It must be using a different file. But try adding `log4j.appender.CONSOLE.threshold=WARN` anyway. What version of Log4J are you using?

Comment: @Andreas Ah okay, so I am guessing that it log4j will just create it's own if you don't specify what you want? How do I get it to notice my properties file? Do I need to adjust a path or something?

Comment: @Andreas okay, so even though my log4j properties are not being used, why is it still logging at all when I comment out the code? I mean, if I comment out the code, the loggers never get initialised, so why does it start logging to console?

Comment: Comment out what? None of the log messages you showed are from the classes you showed. See here about how Log4J initializes: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#Default_Initialization_Procedure

Comment: Okay forget all that follows in this comment, i misread your comment initially-----I mean that I have commented out all the java code for log4j. all of the loggers that i create in my classes are commented out. So I in the state that my code is in at the moment, I shouldn't be getting ANY output from log4j but it is still logging away.

Comment: @Andreas Okay, I didn't realise that log4j would automatically start logging everything, I thought I would have to specifically tell it what I wanted it to log. So now I think that my problem is that I have done a poor job configuring log4j. Thanks for your help, if you want to make an answer out of your comments I will accept that as the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the level to **OFF** which should get rid of all logging. According to the log4j website, valid levels in order of importance are **TRACE**, **DEBUG**, **INFO**, **WARN**, **ERROR**, **FATAL**. There is one undocumented level called **OFF** which is a higher level than FATAL, and turns off all logging.

Are you doing it **correctly** while taking the programmatic approach? This is how I would do it -

```
List<Logger> loggers = Collections.<Logger>list(LogManager.getCurrentLoggers());
loggers.add(LogManager.getRootLogger());
for ( Logger logger : loggers ) {
logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
}
```

**Alternatively**, you could also do `Logger.getRootLogger().removeAllAppenders();
Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(new NullAppender());` for complete silence like a `command line tool`.

Make sure you restart `eclipse` and `clean build` your project for the changes to take effect.

If the above doesnt work - 
Create a `log4j.properties` file and place that file in the `classpath`of your application. Paste the following `contents` in the same -

```
log4j.debug=FALSE
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, R
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=C:/apache-tomcat-5.5.27/logs/testlog.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.SSSS} %p %t %c - %m%n
```

Comment: Yeah I have tried that. tried restarting eclipse, cleaning the project, restarting my laptop, still missing something

Comment: check my edit for the other possible solution. Try that out and let me know how it works out.

Comment: I won't be looking at it again until after the weekend, but I will make an update when I get it working as intended. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Literally just in the door from Driving back from Oktoberfest (sober) Have not looked at it again yet. I am back in work tomorrow so I will be trying it then and I will let you know how I get on.

Comment: Okay, I have literally tried everything. I got to the point where I completely removed log4j from the project. Gone from maven, gone from everywhere. Decided that I would run the code again to see what would happen. Got an error saying that a class in one of the frameworks that I am using from github could not find the log4j class. After looking into it. The telegram interface that I am using from github requires log4j becaus ethe guy who wrote it added it, but he didn't create any way for you to configure it. It's stuck at the settings that he has configured. This is just not good enough...

Comment: for me so I am going to look into a different telegram interface for my project because I only want my code to write to the log/console when I define it.